# Battlefield 3 keeps crashing

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

At random points, while playing (never while changing levels), Battlefield 3 will freeze and crash, and it happens every time I play, sometimes 2-3 times a night (so, within 2-3 hours of gameplay).

Has it happened to anyone else? Does anyone know how to fix this?

All my drivers and Origin are up to date, and I have tried a couple of things, but they wouldn't work.

Comment: Any other symptoms? More info on hardware (GPU, CPU, sound, memory) and drivers (GPU and sound), OS. Any overclocking? Overheating problems: does it still occur if you leave the case open while playing?

Comment: There's no real answer to this. It happens to everyone. Currently Battlefield 3 just isn't very optimized on the PC and hasn't been patched to fix it properly yet.

Comment: Also if you're playing on-line, any of these will failing cause game to crash: the game itself, punkbuster, battelog browser plugin, browser itself, video or sound drivers.

Comment: @Bora No other symptoms. No overclocking, no overheating problems. 4 GB RAM, nVidia GTS 250 GPU, drivers up to date.

Comment: it is unclear if you are referring to singleplayer or multiplayer. If MP, it is "normal" for the game to crash every so many hours.

Comment: @JeffAtwood, Yea I was referring to MP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, Battlefield 3 was patched so that it stopped crashing. Now to catch up with the rest of the world who has reached max level...

Answer (score 1):

I would also get random crashes.  Both during a game and between matches.

The "during a game" crash seemed to have been solved by upgrading my GPU.  I went from a GForce 9800GT to a GForce 560Ti.

*Since the last patch (Dec 6, 2011), my rate of crashing between matches has significantly decreased.  I usually would crash 3-4 times before I would give up.  Last night I crashed 0 times.

Comment: your graphics driver was the same version both before and after the video card update? It is definitely true that the older your video card is, the more neglected it tends to be in terms of driver support and updates...

Comment: @Jeff I believe I was using whatever the beta driver was during that time for both cards.  I don't really like telling people, "buy better hardware" - however, BF3 is such a beautiful game I think it's justified.  I can absolutely say that the monster Karkand patch has completely fixed my crashing problems.  My wife will attest that I played way too much Battlefield this weekend. XD

Answer (score 0):

> At random points, while playing (never while changing levels), Battlefield 3 will freeze and crash, and it happens every time I play, sometimes 2-3 times a night (so, within 2-3 hours of gameplay).

Since you clarified that your question is about multiplayer, yes, this is relatively "normal" for hours of multiplayer as of the current Battlefield 3 patch on the PC version. You may indeed see one crash for every few hours of multiplayer. I know I do...